# Can I subclass a abstract class which has another abstract class which is also subclassed? (C#)

Tags: c#, oop

Lets say I want to design a abstract system for counting sections in a document. I designed two classes, *Document* and *Section*, the document has a list of sections and a method to count them.

```
public abstract class Document {
  List<Section> sections;

  public void addSection(Section section) { 
    sections.Add(section);
  }
  public int sectionCount() { 
    return sections.count;
  } 
}
public abstract class Section {
  public string Text;
}
```

Now, I want to be able to use this code in multipe scenarios. For example, I have Books with Chapters. The Book would be a subclass of Document, and Chapter a subclass of Section. Both classes will contain extra fields and functionality, unrelated to the counting of sections.

The problem I stumble upon now is that because Document contains sections, and not Chapters, the added functionality of Chapter is useless to me, it can only added *as a* section to Book.

I was reading about downcasting, but really think this is not the right way to go. I'm thinking maybe I took the wrong approach altogether.

My question comes to this: How do I design such an abstract system, that can be reused by subclassed objects, and is this the way to go?

Comment: Though I agree that Jon's answer actually answers your question, I would be inclined to take a step back here and ask if maybe you're not suffering from a bit of what I call "Object Happiness Syndrome". Do you _really_ need to treat documents and sections polymorphically across a large set of possible document/section topologies? Does the added complexity and hence added cost of your complicated type relationships "pay for itself" in terms of large-scale code reuse via polymorphism and inheritance, or is it just OOP for the sake of OOP?

Comment: Eric, you might be right. Maybe it is to much and I'm adding to much complexitiy, I was actually wondering about this myself. But I feel I don't have the knowledge to know whether this is the case or not. What I really want to accomplish is to have an abstract "system", which I can re-use and isn't cluttered with things like persistence for example. In the aforementioned case, Book would have the added functionaity of being able to persist itself(using ORM).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need generics:

```
public abstract class Document<T> where T : Section

public abstract class Section

public class Book : Document<Chapter>

public class Chapter : Section
```

You might *also* want to make a section know what kind of document it can be part of. Unfortunately that becomes a lot more complicated:

```
public abstract class Document<TDocument, TSection>
    where TDocument : Document<TDocument, TSection>
    where TSection : Section<TDocument, TSection>

public abstract class Section<TDocument, TSection>
    where TDocument : Document<TDocument, TSection>
    where TSection : Section<TDocument, TSection>

public class Book : Document<Book, Chapter>

public class Chapter : Section<Book, Chapter>
```

I've had to do this in Protocol Buffers, and it's messy - but it does allow you to reference both ways in a strongly-typed way. I'd go for the first version if you can get away with it.

Comment: Thank a lot Jon, was tinkering with day for a whole day! Will read up on generics, but it seems it is what I'm looking for.